# How to display choicefield select widget on template?

Tags: django, forms, drop-down-menu, choicefield

This is my view:

```
CHOICES = (('10','10'), ('20','20'),('30','30'), ('50','50'))

class Droplist (forms.Form):
    number = forms.ChoiceField(choices = CHOICES)    

    def page_objects(request):
        if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
            form = Droplist(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
            if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
                pass #pages = form.cleaned_data['value']
                #return AutoPaginateNode(paginate_by=pages) # Redirect after POST
        else:
            form = Droplist() # An unbound form

        return render_to_response('pagination.html', {'form': form })
```

This is my template:

```
<form action="/submit/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
   {{ form }}
   <input type="submit" value="Select">
</form>
```

how can i render my form, because i need to have a dropdown box with choices on template? what i've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `{{ form.as_p }}`:

```
<form action="/submit/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.as_p }}
   <input type="submit" value="Select">
</form>
```

You can also use `{{ form.as_table }}` to output table rows but you'll need to provide your own `<table>` and `form.as_ul` to output list items:

```
<form action="/submit/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
   <table>
       {{ form.as_table }}
   </table>
   <input type="submit" value="Select">
</form>
```

You can find more information on [Displaying a form using a template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template) on Django's documentation

Comment: it will make the dropdown box in my template?