# Unable to render ChoiceField on template in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, choicefield

I'm trying to show a ChoiceField in a template on Django but I'm unable to make it work.

I have found some solutions here, but seems not work to me ([Possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639238/how-to-display-choicefield-select-widget-on-template)), but I get the error: `too many values to unpack` on line `{{ form.as_p }}`.

So searching on the web, I've found this [Solution](http://www.ilian.io/django-forms-choicefield-and-custom-html-output/) but I'm not able to addapt to my code and make it works. I'm getting an TextField instead a "Dropdown" (in Django Choicefield). And also, this solution list all items on a for loop and I get 4 textfields, instead 2 Choicefields with the elements.

My `forms.py` looks like:

```
class SimpleDeploy(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, networkList, policiesList, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SimpleDeploy, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if networkList and policiesList:
            self.fields['networkPartitions'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=networkList)
            self.fields['applicationPolicies'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=policiesList)
        else:
            self.fields['networkPartitions'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices='No network partitions found')
            self.fields['applicationPolicies'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices='No application policies found')
```

And on my `views.py`:

```
def simpleDeploy(request):
    netList = getDetailsNetworkPartitions(request)
    polList = getDetailsApplicationPolicies(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        abs(5) #Nothing here by the moment
    else:
        simpleForm = SimpleDeploy(networkList=netList, policiesList=polList)
    return render(request, 'apacheStratos/simpleDeploy.html', {'form': simpleForm})
```

Where `netList` and `polList` are list of tuples like:

```
[(u'application-policy-2', u'application-policy-2'), (u'application-policy-1', u'application-policy-1')]
```

And on my template, I'm trying to show the ChoiceField like:

```
<table class="table">
    {% for item in form.networkPartitions.field.choices %}
        <label for="">Network Partitions</label> <input type="choicefield" name="networkPartitions" value="{{item.1}}"/>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for item in form.applicationPolicies.field.choices %}
        <label for="">Application Policies</label> <input type="choicefield" name="applicationPolicies" value="{{item.1}}"/>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

How can I get the choicefield and access to the elements without using a for loop? What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: In `forms.py`, `forms.ChoiceField` is called with a `choices` argument that is a string instead of a tuple. Can you try replacing that?

Comment: you cand make `input type="choicefield"`, only `radio` or `checkbox`

Comment: ChoiceFields are complex fields, and you may also want to render them as a `<select><option>...`, so I wouldn't recommend anything other than a `{{form.networkPartitions}}` that should normally be working.

Comment: Thanks @raphv! With `{{form.networkPartitions}}` it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @raphv, the solution was put `{{form.networkPartitions}}` and `{{form.applicationPolicies}}` on the template. So simple....